# What is the reason of using @Deprecated on method parameter?

Tags: java, annotations, deprecated

The [`@Deprecated`](https://javadoc.scijava.org/Java11/java.base/java/lang/Deprecated.html) annotation target defined as:

```
@Target(value={CONSTRUCTOR, FIELD, LOCAL_VARIABLE, METHOD, PACKAGE, MODULE, PARAMETER, TYPE})
```

On the other hand JavaDoc says:

> Use of the `@Deprecated`  annotation on a local variable declaration or on a parameter declaration or a package declaration has no effect on the warnings issued by a compiler.

What is the possible scenario when `@Deprecated` might be needed on method parameter?

Comment: Interesting question. Without looking it up further, I would assume that it was made either because there was once the idea of a feature for local variables and/or parameters or they wanted to leave the option open in case they find a use for it later.

Comment: Currently, there are no such scenarios.  Perhaps it was defined this way with future capabilities in mind, ones whose discussion so far has only been internal to the Java design team.  (Or the mailing list, which I’m not on.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is backward compatibility.

In Java 5 and 6, `@Deprecated` had no `@Target` meta-annotation.
Java 7 added an `@Target` meta-annotation that had the same effect.

According to the [`@Target` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html):

> If an `@Target` meta-annotation is not present on an annotation type `T`, then an annotation of type `T` may be written as a modifier for any declaration except a type parameter declaration.

Oracle is paranoid about never breaking behavior:  any code that compiles under JDK 6 should also compile under JDK 7.  The extra element types such as `PARAMETER` were included just in case some code somewhere had `@Deprecated` on a formal parameter.

It seems like a bug that the `ANNOTATION_TYPE` element type is missing from the `@Target` meta-annotation, but in fact the following code compiles when using JDK 8 or JDK 11:

```
@Deprecated
public @interface DeprecatedAnnotation { }
```